# Windows CE File Sytem

Tags: windows-mobile, filesystems

I need to discover which file system is installed in a LG phone with windows mobile 6.5. Does anyone knows how?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the device using ActiveSync and open a remote registry editor. Searcht eh `HKLM\Drivers\Active` key for a value of `DSKx:` where x is a number (you can also use `FindFirstStore` and `FindNextStore` for that).
Once you have that you can open the store with [`OpenStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912079.aspx). Then you can find the first partition with `FindFirstPartition` and `FindNextPartition`, open the partition on the store and see the filesystem type (in the `PARTINFO` struct).

Use the [Storage Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914929.aspx) to do all this.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's FAT (altho it doesn't have to be), but that doesn't really help you much.  You can't really stuff with it very easily (either reading or writing).  Also you have to be aware that there are two sets of filesystems.  ROM and RAM, ROM is readonly and isn't always accessible in a read/write form. The ROM filesystem holds most of the system files.  The RAM filesystem is the FAT filesystem where all the user data is stored.

Using the Storage Manager API will give you a breakdown of the RAM filesystem and any attached storage devices.

If you really want to you can access the RAM drive sector by sector using DeviceIoControl DISK_IOCTL_WRITE / DISK_IOCTL_WRITE.

Why do you need to know what the filesystem is?

Update:

So the actaul question is: "I need to know why cant i create more de 1000 files with same extension at same folder. But i can create more than 1000 files from different extensions?"

Actually you can.  The problem is that on Windows Mobile devices (all the I have tried) is that the creation of the directory entry slows down the more directory entries you create.  Once you get to around the 5000 files mark it can take 5 min's to create the directory entry.  I've created test applications where it created zero length file and it took almost 48 hours to create 5000 files on one device!!!  So yes it can but the creation of the files is very slow.  I normally try to limit the number of files in one directory to around the 500 mark.  So my advice would be to split the files into directories with a max for upto 500 files by directory.  Or store the data in your own file format / database.  Either will be speedy.

Comment: I need to know why cant i create more de 1000 files with same extension at same folder. But i can create more than 1000 files from different extensions.

Comment: You have run into what I call a bug in the WinCE implementation of there FAT code.  What I think they are doing is reading the complete directory listing from disk then writing it out every time a directory entry is added.  It means that writing lots of directory entries begins to slow down a lot the more directory entries, once you get to about 5000 directory entries it can take 5 min's to create a file entry.  This happens on all WinMo devices I'v seen...  I would recommend spliting them into directories of no more than 500 files each or store them in your own file format/database.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I've been trying to deal with this issue lately and figured I would add some information here to help anyone else that comes across this issue.

> I need to know why cant i create more de 1000 files with same extension at same folder. But i can create more than 1000 files from different extensions.

This is a limitation on how Windows CE stores file information.

> **Windows Mobile 2003 for Pocket PC, Windows Mobile 2003 for Smartphone, Windows CE Platform Note:** Windows CE cannot store more
>   than 999 files in a directory when the files share the same short file
>   name (that is, the eight-character name, period (.), and 3-character
>   extension). The workaround is to ensure that the short file names are
>   different. For example, if the files are named Longfilename0001.txt
>   through Longfilename1000.txt, place the number at the beginning of the
>   file name instead of at the end.

[FileMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.85).aspx)

Basically when you create a file on WinCE it generates a short file name based on whatever name you gave it. I haven't been able to determine the exact method for generating the short file names on WinCE but it likely involves truncating the name and appending some kind of a counter or a hash to generate a name. The problem is that the it can only generate 999 short names from similar long names. The more variety you have at the start of the file name or the extension the less likely you are to run out of short names.